# How to convert Distinct Count SQL query into a Laravel Eloquent query

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I would like to convert this SQL query into a laravel eloquent query. So I can create

```
SELECT
    count(distinct article_id) as assigned
FROM
    actions
WHERE
    action_id = 1 and
    set_id = 1
```

I can translate the query into a raw request which works

```
DB::table('actions')->select(DB::raw('count(DISTINCT article_id) as assigned'))
        ->where('action_id', 1)
        ->where('set_id', 1)
        ->get();
```

But I would like to figure out how to do it something like this

```
$sets = Set::withCount(['actions as assigned' => function ($q) {
    $q->distinct()
        ->select('article_id')
        ->where('action_id', '=', 1);
}])->get();
```

or this

```
$sets = Set::withCount(['actions as assigned' => function ($q) {
    $q->distinct('article_id')
        ->where('action_id', '=', 1);
}])->get();
```

Eventually I would like to have my Set model contain a scoped method like this

```
public function scopeWithAssignedCount($query){
    $query->withCount(['actions as assigned' => function ($q) {
        $q->distinct('article_id')
            ->where('action_id', '=', 1);
    }])
}
```

So I can add multiple counts to a single call in my controller

```
$sets = Set::withAssignedCount()
    ->withUnassignedCount()
    ->where('palm' => $face)
    ->get();
```

---

### Edited per comments

---

I would like to use something like the below with distinct records.

```
public function scopeWithAssignedCount($query)
{
    $query->withCount(['actions as assigned' => function ($q) {
        $q->where('action_id', 1);
    }]);
}
```

Comment: What SQL should the last query (`Set::withAssignedCount()->[...]`) generate?

Comment: The same as the initial query. I’d like to chain the sql query with others.

Comment: They are quite different, the last query selects from the *sets* table.

Comment: I have done this before without the distinct and it works well. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this query

```
$count = Set::select('article_id as assigned');
if(!empty($action_id)){
   $count = $count->where('action_id', $action_id); 
}
if(!empty($set_id)){
   $count = $count->where('set_id', $set_id); 
}
$count = $count->distinct('article_id')->count('article_id');
```