# Using withCount and Distinct with Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I would like to create a withCount subquery for this model.

Thanks to [Iqbal Butt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55176410/961612) 
I have this snippet for getting the count.

```php
$count = Action::select('article_id as assigned');

if (!empty($action_type_id))
{
    $count = $count->where('action_type_id', $action_type_id);
}

if (!empty($set_id))
{
    $count = $count->where('set_id', $set_id);
}

$count = $count->distinct('article_id')->count('article_id');
```

I would like to execute it like this, but I feel this is painfully flawed.

**Clarification edit**

---

I have a many to many relationship of sets to articles.

Each article has a number of actions.

The actions can have a variety of action types.

I need to count the types of actions for each article in a given set.

---

```php
$sets = Set::withCount(['actions' => function ($q) use ($action_type_id, $set_id) {

    $q->select('article_id as assigned');

    if (!empty($action_type_id))
    {
        $q->where('action_type_id', $action_type_id);
    }

    if (!empty($set_id))
    {
        $q->where('set_id', $set_id);
    }

    $q->distinct('article_id')
      ->count('article_id'); 
    // I believe this is executing inner query
}])

->get();

return $sets;
```

This gives me the error, more then likely because the inner query is executing and without the outer query.

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sets.id' in 
>   'where clause' (SQL: select count(distinct `article_id`) as aggregate
>    from `actions` where `sets`.`id` = `actions`.`set_id` and
>   `action_type_id` = 1 and `set_id` = 1)

---

### Edit per comments

---

### Article Model

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the sets for the article.
     */
    public function sets()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Set::class);
    }

    public function actions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Action::class);
    }
}
```

### Set Model

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Set extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the articles for the set.
     */
    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class);
    }

    public function actions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Action::class);
    }
}
```

### Action Model

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Action extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the set that owns the action.
     */
    public function set()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Set::class);
    }
    /**
     * Get the article that owns the action.
     */
    public function article()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Article::class);
    }
}
```

### Database

**actions**

```php
id
set_id
article_id
action_type_id
```

**sets**

```php
id
name
```

**articles**

```php
id
name
```

**article_set**

```php
id
set_id
article_id
```

Comment: It's hard to know what you are trying to do without more details about your database structure. Can you post the migrations / models of the tables involved? Also, you might be interested in https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#conditional-clauses for conditionally adding clauses to your eloquent queries.

Comment: @Peter Added more info, thanks

Comment: OK thanks. Can you provide more details on what exactly you are trying to get with your query? A count of the articles for a given set? Sorry I'm not clear on what you need.

Comment: Sure, I have edited my question. When looking through my question with fresh eyes, the action_id was very confusing so I changed it to action_type_id. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that will get the data you need although it uses the returned collection to calculate the count.

```
$articles = Set::find($set_id)
    ->articles()
    ->with('actions')
    ->get()
    ->map(function($article){
        $article->action_type_count = $article->actions->unique('action_type')->count();
        return $article;
    });
```

This will give you a collection of articles. The action type count is in a property `action_type_count` on each article in the collection. So to get the first article's action type count:

```
$articles->first()->action_type_count;
```